# Why I have got an error when try save the game ? Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Why i got an error when try saving the game ?

Below is my script :

player.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;

public class player : MonoBehaviour {
    public List<item> itemRaw = new List<item> ();
    public List<item> itemVal = new List<item> ();
    public List<item> itemAdm = new List<item> ();
    public upgradeStorage OnUpStorage1Raw;
    public upgradeStorage OnUpStorage2Raw;
    public upgradeStorage OnUpStorage3Raw;

    public int RawStorage1Level = 0;
    public int totalSlotRawStorage1;
    public int RawStorage2Level = 0;
    public int totalSlotRawStorage2;
    public int RawStorage3Level = 0;
    public int totalSlotRawStorage3;


    public bool RawStorage2Unlock = false;
    public bool RawStorage3Unlock = false;


    public string name;
    public int level;
    public int exp;
    public int coin = 1000000;
    public int gem = 30000;

    public List<GameObject> slotRaw = new List<GameObject> ();
    public List<GameObject> slotVal = new List<GameObject> ();
    public List<GameObject> slotAdm = new List<GameObject> ();

    public List<item> margaretItemSell = new List<item>();
    public List<item> margaretItemBuy = new List<item>();
    public List<productMerchant> productMargaretSell = new List<productMerchant> ();
    public List<productMerchant> productMargaretBuy = new List<productMerchant> ();
    public Dictionary <string, Dictionary <string, int> > productSellMargaret;
    public Dictionary <string, Dictionary <string, int> > productBuyMargaret;

    public player () {

    }

    void Awake () {
        Load ();
    }

    void Update () {
        Save ();
        Debug.Log ("Coin : " + coin);
    }

    public void Save() {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter ();
        FileStream file = File.Create (Application.persistentDataPath + "/saveGame.gd");
        playerData data = new playerData ();

        data.itemRaw = itemRaw;
        data.itemVal = itemVal;
        data.itemAdm = itemAdm;

        bf.Serialize (file, data);
        file.Close ();
    }

    public void Load() {
        if(File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/saveGame.gd")) {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter ();
            FileStream file = File.Open (Application.persistentDataPath + "/saveGame.gd", FileMode.Open);
            playerData data = (playerData) bf.Deserialize (file);
            file.Close ();

            itemRaw = data.itemRaw;
            itemVal = data.itemVal;
            itemAdm = data.itemAdm;

        }
    }
}
```

And i have another script class serializable :

playerData.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[System.Serializable]
public class playerData {
    public List<item> itemRaw = new List<item> ();
    public List<item> itemVal = new List<item> ();
    public List<item> itemAdm = new List<item> ();


}
```

I got this error while the method save() or load()

```
*EndOfStreamException: Failed to read past end of stream.
System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadByte () (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/BinaryReader.cs:293)
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.ReadValue (System.IO.BinaryReader reader, System.Object parentObject, Int64 parentObjectId, System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info, System.Type valueType, System.String fieldName, System.Reflection.MemberInfo memberInfo, System.Int32[] indices) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary/ObjectReader.cs:727) and bla bla blab bla...........*
```

This script just save and load.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution myself.

This error because in my item class there is a gameobject type and in playerData class there also a gameobject data type.

That is not permitted in Saving games binary formated.

Remove the gameobject type from item class and playerData class.

Thanks

Comment: hi @JoeBlow, yes it is working now.. the problem is on gameobject data type. The saving data use binary formatter use gameobject data type is not permitted.